# Proving a double implication with a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I have the following sequence: $\{u_{n}\}$ wich goes as follows:

If $n = 2k-1$, then: $u_{n}= x_{k}$

And if $ n=2k$,  then: $u_{n} = y_{k}$

Both  $\{y_{n}\}$ and  $\{x_{n}\}$ are Cauchy. I need help proving that $\{u_{n}\}$ is cauchy if and only if:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \rho(x_{n},y_{n}) = 0$$

For the first half I used the definition of cauchy sequence: for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a natural number $N$ such that for every $n,m > N$:

$$\Vert u_{n} - u_{m} \Vert < \epsilon$$

Then, I considered the case where $n = 2k -1$. Which implies that

$$u_{n} = x_{k}$$

After that, I set $m = n + 1$. Or in other words, $m = 2k$. Which would, on the other hand, imply that
$$u_{m} = y_{k}$$

Then I simply plugged $x_{k}$ and $y_{k}$ inside the norm.
$$\Vert x_{k} - y_{k} \Vert <  \epsilon$$

Finally concluding with

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \rho(x_{k}, y_{k}) = 0$$

That would be the first half of the proof, but I don't know how to go on the opposite way. I've been struggling with this particular problem for a while now. Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is $\rho$?

Comment: The metric distance. The sequences are in a metric space.

Comment: Hint: The expression $\|u_{m}-u_{n}\|$ can be expressed in $3$ ways in terms of $x_{k}$ and $y_{r}$ for some $r,k\in \mathbb{N}$